# Can't install unity tweak tool. Help please

Tags: unity-tweak-tool

Any body can help me? 
I want to install unity tweak tool but can't.

this is error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 unity-tweak-tool : Depends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Below is the output of `apt-cache policy unity-tweak-tool`:

```
$apt-cache policy unity-tweak-tool
unity-tweak-tool: 
Installed: (none) 
Candidate: 0.0.7ubuntu2 
Version table: 
0.0.7ubuntu2 500
 500 ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
 500 ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages 0.0.7-0~210~ubuntu16.04.1 500
 500 ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages 
 500 ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

`apt-cache policy unity-webapps-common unity-tweak-tool`:

```
unity-webapps-common:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.4.17+15.10.20150616-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.4.17+15.10.20150616-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
unity-tweak-tool:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.0.7ubuntu2
  Version table:
     0.0.7ubuntu2 500
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
```

`sudo apt-get update`:

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease Hit:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                  
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release            
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease     
Hit:5 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease    
Hit:7 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/eiffelstudio-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial
```

`sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
state information... Done Calculating upgrade... Done The following
packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:  
accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas apparmor-easyprof
apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu   click click-apparmor dbus-property-service
fonts-droid-fallback   fonts-noto-mono gir1.2-accounts-1.0
gir1.2-click-0.4 gir1.2-gee-0.8   gir1.2-signon-1.0
indicator-bluetooth indicator-power libandroid-properties1  
libboost-log1.58.0 libc-ares2 libclick-0.4-0 libdbus-cpp5  
libdouble-conversion1v5 libfreerdp-cache1.1 libfreerdp-client1.1  
libfreerdp-codec1.1 libfreerdp-common1.1.0 libfreerdp-core1.1  
libfreerdp-crypto1.1 libfreerdp-gdi1.1 libfreerdp-locale1.1  
libfreerdp-primitives1.1 libfreerdp-utils1.1 libgeonames0 libgflags2v5
libgoogle-glog0v5 libhardware2 libhybris libhybris-common1
libhybris-utils   liblibertine1 liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust0
libmedia1 libmysqlclient20   libnih-dbus1 libpkcs11-helper1
libprocess-cpp3 libqt4-declarative   libqt4-network libqt4-script
libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-xml   libqt4-xmlpatterns
libqt5positioning5 libqtcore4 libqtdbus4 libqtgui4   libsdl-image1.2
libsystemsettings1 libtrust-store2 libubuntu-app-launch2   liburcu4
libva-drm1 libva-x11-1 libvncclient1 libwhoopsie-preferences0  
libwinpr-crt0.1 libwinpr-dsparse0.1 libwinpr-environment0.1
libwinpr-file0.1   libwinpr-handle0.1 libwinpr-heap0.1
libwinpr-input0.1   libwinpr-interlocked0.1 libwinpr-library0.1
libwinpr-path0.1   libwinpr-pool0.1 libwinpr-registry0.1
libwinpr-rpc0.1 libwinpr-sspi0.1   libwinpr-synch0.1
libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 libwinpr-thread0.1 libwinpr-utils0.1  
libxcb-composite0 libxcb-xinerama0 network-manager-openvpn ofono
openvpn   python3-apparmor python3-apparmor-click
python3-click-package python3-gnupg   python3-libapparmor qtcore4-l10n
signon-ui-service suru-icon-theme   system-image-common
system-image-dbus ubuntu-mobile-icons   ubuntu-touch-sounds
ubuntuone-client-data ubuntuone-credentials-common   unity-asset-pool
urfkill vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-samba   whoopsie-preferences Use
'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. 0 to upgrade, 0 to newly
install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

`sudo apt-get install -f`:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
state information... Done The following packages were automatically
installed and are no longer required:   accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas
apparmor-easyprof apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu   click click-apparmor
dbus-property-service fonts-droid-fallback   fonts-noto-mono
gir1.2-accounts-1.0 gir1.2-click-0.4 gir1.2-gee-0.8  
gir1.2-signon-1.0 indicator-bluetooth indicator-power
libandroid-properties1   libboost-log1.58.0 libc-ares2 libclick-0.4-0
libdbus-cpp5   libdouble-conversion1v5 libfreerdp-cache1.1
libfreerdp-client1.1   libfreerdp-codec1.1 libfreerdp-common1.1.0
libfreerdp-core1.1   libfreerdp-crypto1.1 libfreerdp-gdi1.1
libfreerdp-locale1.1   libfreerdp-primitives1.1 libfreerdp-utils1.1
libgeonames0 libgflags2v5   libgoogle-glog0v5 libhardware2 libhybris
libhybris-common1 libhybris-utils   liblibertine1 liblttng-ust-ctl2
liblttng-ust0 libmedia1 libmysqlclient20   libnih-dbus1
libpkcs11-helper1 libprocess-cpp3 libqt4-declarative   libqt4-network
libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-xml  
libqt4-xmlpatterns libqt5positioning5 libqtcore4 libqtdbus4 libqtgui4 
libsdl-image1.2 libsystemsettings1 libtrust-store2
libubuntu-app-launch2   liburcu4 libva-drm1 libva-x11-1 libvncclient1
libwhoopsie-preferences0   libwinpr-crt0.1 libwinpr-dsparse0.1
libwinpr-environment0.1 libwinpr-file0.1   libwinpr-handle0.1
libwinpr-heap0.1 libwinpr-input0.1   libwinpr-interlocked0.1
libwinpr-library0.1 libwinpr-path0.1   libwinpr-pool0.1
libwinpr-registry0.1 libwinpr-rpc0.1 libwinpr-sspi0.1  
libwinpr-synch0.1 libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 libwinpr-thread0.1
libwinpr-utils0.1   libxcb-composite0 libxcb-xinerama0
network-manager-openvpn ofono openvpn   python3-apparmor
python3-apparmor-click python3-click-package python3-gnupg  
python3-libapparmor qtcore4-l10n signon-ui-service suru-icon-theme  
system-image-common system-image-dbus ubuntu-mobile-icons  
ubuntu-touch-sounds ubuntuone-client-data ubuntuone-credentials-common
unity-asset-pool urfkill vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-samba  
whoopsie-preferences Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. 0 to
upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

`sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This
may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.  unity-tweak-tool :
Depends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going to be installed E:
Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`grep -v ^# -r /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe multiverse restricted main
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe multiverse restricted main
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe multiverse restricted main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/eiffelstudio-team-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/eiffelstudio-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/embrosyn-ubuntu-cinnamon-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/embrosyn/cinnamon/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fingerprint-ubuntu-fingerprint-gui-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubuntu-ppa-ubuntu-backports-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mc3man-ubuntu-gstffmpeg-keep-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/moka-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/daily/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pasgui-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pasgui/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/thomas-schiex-ubuntu-blender-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas-schiex/blender/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-atom-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-sublime-text-3-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial main
```

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy unity-tweak-tool`? Which Ubuntu version do you have?

Comment: @N0rbert, unity-tweak-tool:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.0.7ubuntu2
  Version table:
     0.0.7ubuntu2 500
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
     0.0.7-0~210~ubuntu16.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages

Comment: If your Totally new to Ubuntu I wouldn't recommend Tweaking it till you learn your way around. Most Tweaking at your level can be done in System Settings. Is there anything wrong with the Software Center for installing this? Click>>>Dash>>>type Software>>>>>and open Ubuntu Software>>>>Search for >>>>Unity Tweak Tool.

Comment: It seems that main problem is that system was upgraded from previous release and had not-supported PPAs. This disallows software installation.

Comment: @N0rbert, I have installed some programs via terminal. For example atom, sublime text editor, GIMP Image Editor and several other, but stuck in unity-tweak-tool.

Comment: @MuhammadaliNazarov If you use the proper formatting for your most recent edit, you will be able to add more than 10 links. That is, use code formatting (four spaces) not quote formatting (greater-than sign).

Comment: @MuhammadaliNazarov please use code formatting and add output of the following command `grep -v ^# -r /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` to the question (will show all your apt sources lists).

Comment: I can't exactly tell why installation of `unity-tweak-tool` fails. If you can install other packages - maybe your system is healthy. All currently enabled PPAs have packages for xenial, ubuntu's repositories are correctly set. So I have no ideas. You can try other tools - such as Synaptic or `aptitude`. You can search this site for detailed usage instructions.

Comment: @N0rbert, Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

On my Xenial system I can install `unity-tweak-tool` from universe repository and it works normally.

So I recommend to purge its PPA and install version from repository with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

sudo add-apt-repository main # add main repository for sure
sudo add-apt-repository universe # add universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse # add multiverse
sudo add-apt-repository restricted # add restricted

sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:upubuntu-com/gtk3 # to fix apt-get update

sudo ppa-purge ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

If all these steps do not help try to switch to other Ubuntu mirror from *Software & Updates*.

You can try `aptitude` too (installable with `sudo apt-get install aptitude`)

```
sudo aptitude install unity-tweak-tool
```

Comment: [I get this error:]                                                                                                       sudo ppa-purge ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily
Updating packages lists
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/gtk3/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/gtk3/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason

Comment: It's other problem but you can fix it with `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:upubuntu-com/gtk3`.

Comment: helped for ppa-purge. But problem still remains. I can't install it

Comment: Did you followed all instruction? I have just updated it.

Comment: Yes, I did, but problem is there.

Comment: I am totally new in Ubunty.  |||||  sudo add-apt-repository main # add main repository for sure ||||  What does this mean. Just copy paste it?

Comment: Yes, simply copy and paste. "#" is a comment in terminal.

Comment: `sudo ppa-purge ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily`
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: freyja-dev unity-tweak-tool-daily
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: freyja-dev unity-tweak-tool-daily

Comment: Once more time - for successful software installation you should ensure that `sudo apt-get update` ends without errors. Then you can install any packages. `unity-tweak-tool` package depends on `unity-webapps-common` package from *main* repository. Do you have any errors after `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: There is no any errors.

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy unity-webapps-common unity-tweak-tool` (if possible please add it to your question)?

Comment: I opened Synaptic Package Manager, Found there unity-webapps-common. It says that this package is broken

Comment: Synaptic is good tool, we can trust it :) Close Synaptic and try `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: @N0bert, Still problem is there.

Comment: OK. Please add the following output to the question - complete output of the following commands: `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`, `sudo apt-get install -f`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`.

Comment: output is nothing for `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: The last idea I have is to autoremove old packages with `sudo apt-get autoremove`, then clean cache with `sudo apt-get clean` and start over.

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. I think problem is in that unity-webapps-common package. Synaptics still says that it is broken.