# unable to install unity-tweak-tool in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome-tweak-tool, unity-tweak-tool

I used to have `Tweak-Tools` but it was faulty and stopped working all the time. I didn't have `unity-tweak-tool`. I had the `gnome-tweak-tool`. So I removed the whole thing using purge when facing the problem below:

```
atenagm@atenagm-K46CB:~$ sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
unity-tweak-tool : Depends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

but even after that, I faced the same problem. I've also tried `$sudo apt-get install -f` and all other solutions found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874820/how-to-resolve-the-errors-that-show-up-when-trying-to-install-unity-tweak-tool) but none of them worked.

I was thinking that maybe installing other desktop environments might be the cause. I once intalled `gnome3` but the gui faced problems and I deleted all the dependencies. After restarting, problem had still remained, so I went for other environments like KDE. That solved the problem, though now I am still on unity desktop and no KDE desktop environment is running on the system. Might this be the problem? If so, how can I fix it and go back to the normal unity with all the functions such as `unity-tweak-tool`? and if not, how can I install `unity-tweak-tool`?

P.S. Here is the output of installing it using `gdebi`:

```
atenagm@atenagm-K46CB:~$ sudo gdebi unity-tweak-tool_0.0.7ubuntu2_all.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Cannot install 'unity-webapps-common'
atenagm@atenagm-K46CB:~$ sudo gdebi unity-webapps-common_2.4.17+15.10.20150616-0ubuntu2_all.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Cannot install 'unity-webapps-service'
```

There is no error when performing `$sudo apt-get update` or `$sudo apt-get check` or any other`apt` commands. The output of `$sudo apt-get install -f` is also as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-109 linux-headers-4.4.0-109-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Which I solved this issue also by performing an autoremove.

**Update note:** from chat with N0rbert we determined that main problem was
`kubuntu-ppa/backports` PPA. It messed Qt dependencies of `unity-tweak-tool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in other [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1001078/66509) I can't reproduce this problem on clean installation of Xenial without PPAs even with [HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) installed.

After some trial and error I found the clue - its KDE PPA (`ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports`).

## Forward way (how to get there)

I describe shortly how to get there.

1. Install Xenial and upgrade it.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
2. Install kubuntu-desktop package

   ```
   sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
   sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```
3. Try to install `unity-tweak-tool` here (no KDE PPA yet)

   ```
   apt-get install --simulate unity-tweak-tool # ok
   ```
4. Add KDE PPA

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   sudo apt-get autoremove

   apt-get install --simulate unity-tweak-tool # fail! (see OP error message)
   ```

   So `unity-tweak-tool` does not install after upgrading KDE from their PPA.

## Backward way (how to get out there)

### Warning: following steps are provided without any warranty. Do not try it at home. It's very difficult and dangerous way, but who forced you to add kubuntu-ppa?

1. Save current list of software and install Meld to make comparison later:

   ```
   dpkg -l > dpkg_-l_before.txt
   sudo apt-get install meld
   ```
2. Prepare and purge PPA:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
   sudo ppa-purge -i -y ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
   sudo apt-get install -f -y
   ```
3. Find and purge obsolete packages (many of them came from KDE PPA)

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | grep ^rc | awk '{print $2}')
   sudo apt-get purge $(aptitude search ~o | awk '{print $2}')
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
4. Save list of KDE packages to file and then purge them

   ```
   dpkg -l | grep "^ii\|^ri\|^ic" | grep ~ppa | awk '{print $2}' > kde_packages.txt
   sudo apt-get purge $(cat kde_packages.txt)
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   dpkg -l | grep "^ri\|^ic" | awk '{print $2}' > kde_packages2.txt
   sudo apt-get purge $(cat kde_packages2.txt)
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
5. To reinstall official KUbuntu versions of KDE packages you should do the following:

   ```
   sudo aptitude install kubuntu-desktop
   ```

   Don't agree with removing, press <kbd>n</kbd> for next solution and wait for something like

   ```
   Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
   The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

        Downgrade the following packages:
   1)     libqt5core5a [5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 (now) -> 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 (xenial-updates)]
   2)     libqt5dbus5 [5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 (now) -> 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 (xenial-updates)]
   3)     libqt5network5 [5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 (now) -> 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 (xenial-updates)]
   4)     libqt5qml5 [5.6.1-4ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4 (now) -> 5.5.1-2ubuntu6 (xenial)]
   5)     libqt5sql5 [5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 (now) -> 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 (xenial-updates)]
   6)     libqt5sql5-mysql [5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 (now) -> 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 (xenial-updates)]
   7)     libqt5sql5-sqlite [5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 (now) -> 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 (xenial-updates)]
   8)     libqt5xmlpatterns5 [5.6.1-2build1~~xenialoverlay1~4 (now) -> 5.5.1-2build1 (xenial)]
   9)     qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel [5.6.1-4ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4 (now) -> 5.5.1-2ubuntu6 (xenial)]



   Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]y
   The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
   ...
   ```
6. After KDE reinstallation you can install `unity-tweak-tool`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
   ```
7. Save new list of software and compare it with previous one with Meld

   ```
   dpkg -l > dpkg_-l_after.txt
   meld dpkg_-l_before.txt dpkg_-l_after.txt
   ```

   Then you can manually install missed packages.

## Conclusion

### If unsure - never install such big projects as KDE from PPAs. It's very difficult to solve dependency problems in such situations. Version from official repository was tested for dependencies, version from PPA may break whole system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this didn't even work :( I really don't know what to do

Comment: `$sudo apt-get install -f` removes the dependencies downloaded by `wget`.

Comment: Could you please try `sudo apt-get install aptitude && sudo aptitude install unity-tweak-tool` or Gdebi (see update above).

Comment: unfortunately no result. see the edit in the post please. aptitude didn't work also:(

Comment: How about `sudo aptitude install unity-tweak-tool`?

Comment: that didn't work either.

Comment: It becomes interesting. Do you have any problems with other packages? Errors on apt-get or something. Do `sudo apt-get check`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, `sudo apt-get install -f`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a` produce any errors or warnings (if so, please add them to the question)? Have you enabled all repositories (main, universe, multiverse, restricted; xenial-updates; security)?

Comment: no special errors

Comment: how should I understand if all repos are enabled?

Comment: *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`) may help: open it and look to *Ubuntu Software* and *Updates* tabs.

Comment: they are all ticked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72436/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-athena).